# View pdf file in another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Here have code to view pdf file and currently the file can be viewed  in the same page.I want to display file in new page when the linkbutton clicked in gridview. As understood that Literal embed link needs to be changed but I am not sure about that. My question is how to view the file in new page?

Gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="comName" HeaderText="Company Name" SortExpression="comName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sName" HeaderText="Stock Name" SortExpression="sName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="annDate" HeaderText="Date Announced" SortExpression="annDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="fYearEnd" HeaderText="Financial Year End" SortExpression="fYearEnd" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="quarterr" HeaderText="Quarter" SortExpression="quarterr" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QFREDate" HeaderText="Financial Period Ended " SortExpression="QFREDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="figure" HeaderText="Figure" SortExpression="figure" />
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

code behind for view:

```
 protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">";
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
        embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
        embed += "</object>";
        ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?Id="), id);
    }
```

FileCS.ashx code:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  fName, contentType, data FROM announ WHERE Id=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["data"];
                contentType = sdr["contentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["fName"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Charset = "";
    if (context.Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
    {
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    }
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your link button add OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

this will open a new tab.

Comment: lets say the new page is Pdf.aspx. how to do that?